# Пакетный POST / PATCH запрос (DRF / Requests)

Tags: python, http, rest, django-rest-framework

Возник вопрос, существует ли возможность отправлять / обновлять данные пакетно по REST API (1 http запрос, который создает множество строк в бд, как *INSERT INTO `table` (c1, c2, c3...) VALUES (v1, v2, v3...), ... ,(v1, v2, v3)*)

Есть json (постоянно обновляемый) на 30+ тысяч строк и есть API на DRF. Загрузка и обновление данных занимает громадное кол-во времени, и хотелось бы отправлять большой пакет данных одним запросом.
Не могу найти ничего ни в документации DRF, ни в гугле.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если в эндпоинт сразу залетает весь файл:

1. Если джанга свежая (с асинхроном) можно побить файл на чанки и пустить обработку/сохранение в асинхроне
2. Если джанга без асинка, можно подвязать в стек celery/redis и в отдельных тасках обрабатывать эти файлы